# How to limit python script so that it can't access local resources?

Tags: python, api, security, flask

I am working on a project that allows users to upload a python script to an API and run it on a schedule. Currently, I'm trying to figure out a way to limit the functionality of the script so that it cannot access local files, mess with the flask server running the API, etc. Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this? Is there anyway to make it so only specific libraries are available for importing?

Answer (score 0):

Running other scripts on your server is serious security issue. If you are trying to deploy Python interpreter on your web application, you can try with something like [judge0 - GitHub](https://github.com/judge0/judge0). It is free if you deploy it yourself and it will run scripts safely inside containers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to ensure the user running the script is not root, but a user specifically designed for this task (e.g. part of a group that can only read and not write or execute). This means at minimum you should ensure all files have the appropriate mode. Then you can just use a pipe or something to run the script.

Alternatively, you could use a runtime that’s not “local”, like a VM or compute service (AWS lambda, etc). The latter would be simplest, and there’s lots of vendors who offer compute service with programmatic api.